# Destroying Session and User Data on browser close ( PHP)

Tags: php, session

I know this question have been asked lot of times that how to track online users on a site using php , what i do is very basic if a user is logged in to my site i save their data to a database and once they click logout i destroy their session and delete that username from my database.

The real problem occurs when a user directly close the browser coz than i have no way to run a mysql query to my database and looks like they are still logged in though they are not.

I don't want to set any time to destroy cookies or sessions because that is not the appropriate way to do it let say i set time to 30min and a user closed the browser in just a min , so for 29 min he will appear online so i don' t want that.

Thanks

Comment: You could use javascript to ping the user every {interval} and delete your session in your sql on timeout. I'd recommend though not to delete, just to set to offline, so a user can pick up a session again in case of temporary connection problems

Comment: @DanSurfrider that will work but the idea of a request every x seconds scares me..imagine the amount of requests per day the server will have to handle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use web-socket i.e.: http://html5demos.com/web-socket when your user closes the browser, the connection will be interrupted, then you set it as offline, but will only work on modern browsers.

However you still can do something like web-socket using `push-stream` to monitor your users.

But, if you use sessions, you can setup your timer diconnect to the same time that the session disconnects. PHP is 15 minutes as default (you can customize). So if your user keep your site open by this time but don't make requests, after this time, his session will be closed, even if the browser still open.

Comment: I think you can use JavaScript to check when the user closes the browser and send a ajax request and update your database

Comment: ok i will try with web-socket but it's shocking that a language like php is not flexible at all

Comment: @kevin This isn't a limitation of PHP.

Comment: @Gerep :- ya that can be done but onbeforeload and unload methods of javascript do it on everypage reload, can you suggest any function that only specify the browser close event

Comment: @kevin that solution will not ensure what you want. Have lot of ways to that prevent that events to be dispatch. Like, drop connection, or kill browser process. Anyway you always will need to timeout check the user browser. Like keep-alive protocol. This docs are good studding start for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive

Comment: @ Gabriel ... that seems to be awesome i believe keep alive will do the trick for me ... thanks dude

Comment: @GabrielGartz both solutions will work fine..one will complement the other

Answer (score 2):

There is better solution, use JavaScript to send an AJAX request to your server on "onBeforeUnload" event. This way the script will ensure the session and DB record are only deleted when the user is leaving the website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: /controller/action/clear
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you must store also time when user was reload page. after authentication, after click some link or something else, you must store/update in database all this actions.

after this, you should check that, if user was visit on site or was reload page about 15 minute ago, that he is not online.

Comment: Its a way but its no accurate as kevin need it to be